# Why docker swarm use the secrets path and not the secrets value?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want to use in docker swarm secrets.
I init the docker swarm.

I create the secrets with:

```
echo "password1" | docker secret create my_mysql_wordpress_password -
echo "password2" | docker secret create my_mysql_root_password -
```

Then I deploy the stack with:
`docker stack deploy -c mysql.yml mysql`

The mysql.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:3306:3306"     
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=false"
    environment:
        - MYSQL_USER=wordpress_admin
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/my_mysql_wordpress_password
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/my_mysql_root_password
    secrets:
      - my_mysql_wordpress_password
      - my_mysql_root_password
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - traefik-backend

secrets:
  my_mysql_wordpress_password:
    external: true
  my_mysql_root_password:
    external: true


volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
       o: bind
       type: none
       device: /data/mysql_data

networks:
  traefik-backend:
    external: true
```

Now the database server starts.
When I try now to connect to the server, the password from root is not "password2" (the value from the secret), the password is "/run/secrets/my_mysql_root_password"

What is wrong? Why is the password the run-String and not the value from the secret?

Comment: I am facing the same issue - Could you find an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in different documentation, it seems that the solution is NOT clear. I do not understand how/why it works either, but here is what worked for me:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:3306:3306"     
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=false"
    environment:
        - MYSQL_USER=wordpress_admin
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/my_mysql_wordpress_password
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/my_mysql_root_password
    secrets:
      - my_mysql_wordpress_password
      - my_mysql_root_password
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - traefik-backend

secrets:
  my_mysql_wordpress_password:
    external: true
  my_mysql_root_password:
    external: true
...
```

Adding "_FILE" to the environment variables did the trick.