# Docker secret not load

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

I have an env variable called MY_KEY
I want to store this variable as a docker secret

my scenario is:
1- `printf "This is a secret" | docker secret create my_secret_data -`
2- docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  api:
    image: myimage
    command: sh -c "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 node.wsgi:application"
    secrets:
      - my_secret_data
    environment:
      - MY_KEY=/run/secrets/my_secret_data

secrets:
  my_secret_data:
    external: true
```

3- run `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml myapp`

But when container started, MY_KEY value is `/run/secrets/my_secret_data` instead of `This is a secret`

Comment: Where inside the container are you reading the file?

Comment: @BMitch 
I read MY_KEY inside django app :
```
from django.conf import settings  , 

settings.MY_KEY

```

Comment: That should be in your question, along with enough detail for others to reproduce. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it: you have two alternatives.
Either you try to do it as described in [Why docker swarm use the secrets path and not the secrets value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748465/why-docker-swarm-use-the-secrets-path-and-not-the-secrets-value)
or you write your own interceptor that is loaded before the application starts up. As it is not entirely clear what application you're deploying I can't  produce an example that would work.